# Hibernate @TenantId annotation doesn't work with @Embedded class

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, multi-tenant

I'm using Spring boot v3.0.1 and hibernate v6.1.6.Final. I'm trying the @TenantId annotation in my entity class. This annotation works fine if I declare the annotation in the entity class directly. But if I create a @Embeddable class and then declare the @TenantId annotation inside it, then the application doesn't start.

Below is the sample code:

BaseEntity.Java

```
import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Embeddable;
import jakarta.persistence.MappedSuperclass;
import org.hibernate.annotations.TenantId;

@MappedSuperclass
@Embeddable
public class BaseEntity {

  @TenantId
  @Column(name = "tenant_id", nullable = false)
  private String tenantId;

  public BaseEntity() {
  }

  public BaseEntity(String tenantId) {
    this.tenantId = tenantId;
  }

  public String getTenantId() {
    return tenantId;
  }

  public void setTenantId(String tenantId) {
    this.tenantId = tenantId;
  }
}
```

Person.java

```
import jakarta.persistence.*;


import java.util.Objects;

@Entity
public class Person {

    @Id @GeneratedValue private Long id;

    @Embedded
    private BaseEntity baseEntity;

    private String name;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public BaseEntity getBaseEntity() {
        return baseEntity;
    }

    public void setBaseEntity(BaseEntity baseEntity) {
        this.baseEntity = baseEntity;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person{" + "id=" + id + ", name='" + name + '\'' + '}';
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Person person = (Person) o;
        return Objects.equals(id, person.id) && Objects.equals(baseEntity, person.baseEntity) && Objects.equals(name, person.name);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id, baseEntity, name);
    }
}
```

Error message:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path
> resource
> [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]:
> [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory;
> nested exception is org.hibernate.cfg.NotYetImplementedException:
> Still need to wire in composite in-memory value generation   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1751)
> ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599)
> ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
> ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
> ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
> ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
> ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
> ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]   at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1130)
> ~[spring-context-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]   at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:905)
> ~[spring-context-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]   at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584)
> ~[spring-context-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]   at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730)
> ~[spring-boot-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]   at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:432)
> ~[spring-boot-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]   at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
> ~[spring-boot-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]   at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302)
> ~[spring-boot-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]   at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1291)
> ~[spring-boot-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]   at
> example.springdata.jpa.hibernatemultitenant.partition.Application.main(Application.java:9)
> ~[classes/:na] Caused by: jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException:
> [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory;
> nested exception is org.hibernate.cfg.NotYetImplementedException:
> Still need to wire in composite in-memory value generation   at
> org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:421)
> ~[spring-orm-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]   at
> org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396)
> ~[spring-orm-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]   at
> org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:352)
> ~[spring-orm-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1797)
> ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1747)
> ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]   ... 15 common frames omitted Caused
> by: org.hibernate.cfg.NotYetImplementedException: Still need to wire
> in composite in-memory value generation   at
> org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel$CompositeGenerationStrategyPairBuilder.buildPair(EntityMetamodel.java:601)
> ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.buildGenerationStrategyPair(EntityMetamodel.java:460)
> ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.(EntityMetamodel.java:296)
> ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.(AbstractEntityPersister.java:728)
> ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:152)
> ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
> Method) ~[na:na]   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
> ~[na:na]   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
> ~[na:na]   at
> java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
> ~[na:na]   at
> java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
> ~[na:na]   at
> org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:92)
> ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:75)
> ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.processBootEntities(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:278)
> ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.finishInitialization(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:211)
> ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.RuntimeMetamodelsImpl.finishInitialization(RuntimeMetamodelsImpl.java:60)
> ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:311)
> ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:415)
> ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1425)
> ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]   at
> org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:66)
> ~[spring-orm-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]   at
> org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:376)
> ~[spring-orm-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]   at
> org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409)
> ~[spring-orm-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]   ... 19 common frames omitted

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

You can use inheritance to achieve the desired result (moving the tenant_id column out of the entity), rather than the `@Embedded` annotation. Here's how:

For the `BaseEntity` class (please forgive my use of Lombok annotations)

```
import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.MappedSuperclass;
import org.hibernate.annotations.TenantId;

@MappedSuperclass
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public abstract class BaseEntity {

  @TenantId
  @Column(name = "tenant_id", nullable = false)
  private String tenantId;
}
```

Then in the `Person` class, simply extend `BaseEntity`

```
import jakarta.persistence.*;


import java.util.Objects;

@Entity
public class Person extends BaseEntity {

    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue private Long id;

    private String name;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person{" + "id=" + id + ", name='" + name + '\'' + '}';
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        // TODO implement a suitable equals method
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return 0; // TODO implement a suitable hashcode method
    }
}
```